# Parse email address with Laravel

Tags: php, parsing, laravel, laravel-5

How could I parse email addresses which are in this format :

```
"Bob Smith" <bob@company.com>, joe@company.com, "John Doe"<john@company.com>
```

And get an array like this :

```
array(
     'bob@company.com'=>'Bob Smith'
     'joe@company.com'=>''
     'john@company.com'=>'John Doe'
);
```

We have something similar to  [mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses()](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses) with Laravel?

Comment: Just call the function then or make a class that call the function in case some changes occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract all emails from string with this function:

```
function extract_email_address_from_string ($string) {
    foreach(preg_split('/\s/', $string) as $token) {
        $email = filter_var(filter_var($token, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if ($email !== false) {
            $emails[] = $email;
        }
    }

    return $emails;
}
```